# What is the best AWS service to store small amount of data

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I have a use case where I need to store some data (just a few hundreds) of records with just one column (a string similar to a UUID) and timestamp.
Also I need to have an efficient way to avoid duplicates of the main column (not the timestamp) and perform reads/writes/deletes frequently.

I'm currently using an RDS database but it seems overkill for this.

Using AWS services what would be the best way, taking in consideration that performance and cost are important.

Comment: I would look at DynamoDB for that

Comment: @MarkB I already use DynamoBD in the same project but I'm having difficulties to avoid duplicated.

Comment: That sounds like a separate question you should ask here then. Or maybe avoiding duplicates in DynamoDB is the question you should have asked.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [Amazon MemoryDB](https://aws.amazon.com/jp/memorydb/), probably the best options you can get for price/performance if you have tiny data set, but really frequent updates/reads. Because it's im-memory db, it's really fast and low latency and you won't pay much for one instance cluster with smallest Node type.

[DynamoDB](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb) Can be cheap while performant, but price will highly depend on you usage patters. Probably the cheapest option.

Another option can be [Aurora Serverless](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/serverless/) if you want regular RDS, depends on your usage pattern in the end of the day might be more expensive option.

All those databases can be used to detect duplications at insert/update time, making your app resilient to records duplication.

Answer (score -1):

Frankly, you could just use **Amazon S3**.

Think of it as a **NoSQL database**:

- The `Key` is the Key of the object (which guarantees uniqueness)
- The `Value` is the content of the object

You could do fancy stuff [Filtering and retrieving data using Amazon S3 Select - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/selecting-content-from-objects.html), but frankly I'd suggest you just **read the whole object and parse it in your code**. It sounds like your items would be small enough to keep in memory.

To update information in the object, **just PUT the whole object again** with the updated information. It would be very fast since your data would be kept in memory within your app.

The only issue would be if you have **simultaneous updates** of the data due to parallel-running of the application.

Comment: Keeping in memory is not really a good option because (I forgot to mention before) the code will run in a Lambda function that will live just for a few seconds, and parallel-running will happen a lot.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear... Your code would retrieve the data from Amazon S3, just like it would retrieve the data from DynamoDB (via its Key). It's just that if you want to update the data, then the object needs to be written completely, rather than saying something like "increment the value stored at this key". Using S3 as a NoSQL database is quite common for situations that don't require high-speed updates. For example, Amazon.com keeps all historical orders in S3 because orders become read-only after 1 year (no returns accepted) and are less-often accessed so its okay if is is slower.